# R: finite-population-corrected cluster-robust standard errors

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, regression, variance

**How can we calculate finite-population-corrected (FPC) cluster-robust standard errors in R?**

There is no function to calculate FPC cluster-robust standard errors in R.

The following function calculates cluster-robust standard errors, without FPC.

```
clx <-
 function(fm, dfcw, cluster){
          library(sandwich)
          library(lmtest)
          M <- length(unique(cluster))
          N <- length(cluster)
          dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-fm$rank))
          u  <- apply(estfun(fm),2,
                          function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum))
          vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(u)/N)*(fm$df / (fm$df - (M -1)))
          coeftest(fm, vcovCL) }
```

I am very close to writing a custom function to calculate FPC cluster-robust standard errors in R, but there is a mathematical mistake in the last line.

```
clx_FPC <-
 function(fm, dfcw, cluster){
          library(sandwich)
          library(lmtest)
          M <- length(unique(cluster))
          N <- length(cluster)
          dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-fm$rank))
          u  <- apply(estfun(fm),2,
                          function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum))
          vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(u)/N)*(fm$df / (fm$df - (M -1)))
          vcovCL_FPC <- (sqrt( (N_full - n_sample) / (N_full - 1) ))*(vcovCL)
          coeftest(fm, vcovCL_FPC) 
          }
```

The code runs without an error, but the math is wrong in the object `vcovCL_FPC`. We cannot simply multiply the covariance matrix by the FPC as a scalar, because then the FPC would be incorrectly affected when we calculate the standard errors, dividing by *n* and taking the square-root of the diagonal. In this case the FPC will be too small, and the SEs will too large.

Comment: Have a look at the `clusterSE` package and/or `multiwayvcov` package. There are boostrap versions available and it looks like the `multiwayvcov` function has a df_correction that might help.

Comment: @lmo I do not see how I get from a df correction to FPC